# CSS element's position with Absolute Changes on mobile (same-size screen)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I always find myself confused with this absolute position in CSS, the problem is when i was trying on chrome and firefox it was fine, even when i was changing the browser's screen size to see the responsive act but with the same screen size on mobile my absolute element moves some pixels up.

[image: absolute position on mobile and desktop same size]

```
#square-box-tratamiento-nebulizado {
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:-webkit-right;
    z-index:1000;
    /*margin-top:-63px;*/
    position:absolute;
   bottom: 61px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
/*etiqueta pulverizado*/
#square-box-tratamiento-pulverizado {
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:-webkit-right;
    z-index:1000;
    /*margin-top:-29px;*/
    position:absolute;
        bottom: 26px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x7b8hp9b/

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using `top` instead of `bottom` ? is it not because of the horizontal scroll bar ?

Comment: @skam it is exactly because of scroll bar i fixed it and im writing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as we figured out and if you see in picture there is a scroll bar that appearing in bottom of desktop version no in mobile that cause the problem. i fixed it like this: for both labels we moved the whole div to top of the container and changed the css like this and put a margin top:

```
#square-box-tratamiento-nebulizado {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: -webkit-right;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-top: 427px;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
```

and we put a media query for margin-top to change it if the size of screen changes